# How do I prevent sugar from burning/sticking on cast iron grill?

Tags: grilling, cast-iron

I've got a Lodge reversible cast iron grill/griddle ([this model](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00008GKDQ)). The griddle side works great, and I've had no problems with food sticking or burning. But I've had less luck with the grill side. Specifically, any time I grill meats that have been marinated in a sugary marinade, the sugar burns and sticks to the grill.

Is that to be expected? Is there some kind of technique to grilling foods with sugar on cast iron I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this problem making Bulgogi. I found that the surface should be well oiled/greased, and as much marinade drained from the meat as is possible. Baking soda and vinegar did a bangup job cleaning off the residue - my griddle was fine, but you may need to re-season.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is expected. The cast iron turns the sugar into caramel, which is one of the stickiest substances which you will ever encounter in a kitchen, and then on to charcoal.

I don't know why you marinate your meat in sugar, but if you do, you have to either not grill it, or live with the mess.